# Separating JSON Objects

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I want to separate month_year to the value how can I do that?

[Screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4lMd.png)

> SAMPLE OUTPUT:
>   APR_2017
>   :
>   "974144328"
>   AUG_2017
>   :
>   "1021696328"
>   DEC_2017
>   :
>   "1069248328"
>   FEB_2017
>   :
>   "950368328"
>   JAN_2017
>   :
>   "938480328"
>   JAN_2018
>   :
>   "1081136328"
>   JUL_2017
>   :
>   "1009808328"
>   JUN_2017
>   :
>   "997920328"
>   MAR_2017
>   :
>   "962256328"
>   MAY_2017
>   :
>   "986032328"
>   NOV_2017
>   :
>   "1057360328"
>   OCT_2017
>   :
>   "1045472328"
>   SEP_2017
>   :
>   "1033584328"

JQUERY CODE:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "overall-sales-chart.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {activator:activator, data_show: data_show, start: start_date, end: end_date},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log("error");
    }
});
```

PHP CODE:

```
$start = new DateTime("2017-01-01");
$end = new DateTime("2018-01-01");

$smonth = (int)$start->format('Y')*12+(int)$start->format('n');
$emonth = (int)$end->format('Y')*12+(int)$end->format('n');

$firstmonth = min($smonth, $emonth);
$lastmonth = max($smonth, $emonth);
$months = array();

for ($i = $firstmonth; $i <= $lastmonth; $i++) {
    $thism = new DateTime(sprintf('%04d-%02d-01', intdiv($i, 12), $i % 12));
    $months[] = strtoupper($thism->format('M_Y'));
}

$m_total = implode(',', preg_replace('/^(.*)$/', 'SUM($1) AS $1', $months));

$sql = "SELECT $m_total FROM temp_sg_screen_sto_72_mos_summary";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
} 

print json_encode($data);
```

Comment: your json format is not valid.

Comment: @Wils how come?

Comment: `data['JAN_2017']`?

Comment: you missing } at the end, and each key need a quote.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal I just want to get separate JAN_2017 and 938480328 and put it into a variable so that I can use it in my chart sorry I am a newbie Im just following tutorials

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data={
'JAN_2017': "938480328",
'FEB_2017': "950368328",
'MAR_2017': "962256328", 
'APR_2017':"974144328",
'MAY_2017': "986032328"
};
$.each(data, function( index, value ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + value );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here's a snippet for it.
And, in your case.

```
     success: function(data){
      $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
        console.log( index + ": " + value );
    });
}
```

Comment: There is an error

Comment: you should check your JSON syntax first.

Comment: Please see my code above